# Store Text File Online Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cloud, dropbox

I'm developing a Mac application in Objective-C, and I'd like to store either a database (spreadsheet type of file pretty much) or a text file online. Every time a user runs the app, I'd like for it to retrieve that file, modify it, and upload it back up to the server.

I've been thinking of a couple of options, which I've listed below:

-Amazon S3: the advantage is it seems relatively easy to implement. Inconvenients: the fees, even as small as they are, could add up, and it's probably way overkill.

-Dropbox: the main advantage is it's free, and probably quite simple to implement. The disadvantage to this service is it's probably not tailored for the type of action I'm trying to run.

-Google Docs: best guess on my part so far, because it's free, and easy to implement (I think) with Google's Objective-C APIs. I was thinking it might have the same problem as Dropbox (it's not made for this type of thing), but I'm not really sure.

So, to resume, does anyone know of a simple, free, and easy way to modify a text file stored online from an Objective-C application? Out of these three, which one would you suggest, and why, or do you have any other suggestions?

EDIT: I'm not sure I've made this clear, but ideally, I'm looking for a free service that doesn't necessarily offer much space (I don't need that much), but lets me make a good number of requests.

Comment: Remember that with Amazon S3 you only pay for your consumption - also they have an iOS SDK page to get you started.

Comment: That's true, especially since my application won't have much traffic. However, this page outlines the pricing (http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), and I just don't understand what category editing a text file would fall into.

Comment: @boopyman: There's no concept of editing in S3. You just retrieve it and later store a new version. You pay for one GET, one PUT and the outgoing bytes. If you cache the document on the client, you may also avoid most of the GETs and bytes.

Comment: Ah, I see - so it _could_ end up being costly... See my edit above ^.

Comment: Perhaps. If the document isn't shared, caching can make this relatively cheap (a single PUT per edit). If it *is* shared, you might still benefit from caching if you use [Cache-Control](http://www.labnol.org/internet/lower-amazon-s3-bill-improve-website-loading-time/5193/) to avoid transferring data unnecessarily. There's no way you'll get to use S3 for free, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after realizing there are several issues for me regarding Amazon S3 (lack of credit card, etc, no Paypal option, etc...), I have decided to use Google Docs to store a 'database' in a spreadsheet.

Since I don't have a big user base, this has many advantages, including: free, easy to implement, and *really* fast.

Using Google's GData libraries (in particular the Docs and Spreadsheet libraries), I only took me a couple of hours to have the whole system set up. My only regret is that the Spreadsheet library doesn't let you set sorting and formatting for a particular spreadsheet.